# Perl array in scalar context

Tags: perl

I am a newbie in Perl. I'm trying to understand Perl context. I've the following Perl code.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my @even = [ 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 ];
my @odd = [ 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 ];
my $even1 = @even;
print "$even1\n";
```

When I execute the code, I get the following output ...

```
1
```

But, as I've read, the following scalar context should **places the number of elements in the array** in the scalar variable.

```
my $even1 = @even;
```

So, this is bizarre to me. And, what's going inside the code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct syntax for defining your arrays is

```
my @even = ( 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 );
my @odd  = ( 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 );
```

When you use square brackets, you're actually creating a *reference* (pointer) to an anonymous array, and storing the reference in `@even` and `@odd`. References are scalars, so the length of `@even` and `@odd` is one.

See the [Perl references tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more on references.

Answer (score 4):

By using square brackets in Perl, you are creating an array reference rather than an actual array. 
You can read up on how references work in the manual: `perldoc perlreftut`. Replace the square brackets with round parentheses and the code will do what you expect:

```
my @even = ( 0, 2, 4, 6, 8 );
my @odd = ( 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 );
my $scalar = @even;
print "$scalar\n";
```

will print

```
5
```